# How to move from Asana to Trello

Tags: trello, asana

I want to move all the data for one project. Is it possible (migrate)?

I didn't found this option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [no official support from Trello](http://help.trello.com/article/751-importing-data-into-trello), but [Todoport is a webapp](https://todoport.com/) which offers migration between various Todo apps

Comment: Thank you. I must know. Did you knew about this web app, or did you search it for me?

Comment: @Amina I searched for a bit. Welcome :)

Comment: "Todoport has shut down indefinitely."

Answer (score 1):

Use [Zapier](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAAahUKEwjw48Pd3ZDIAhVL74AKHYaiAGY&url=https%3A%2F%2Fzapier.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNExHqHMTW7Ix273nP5XzbmM7oyUZw&sig2=ZhZrY1GEidcKEKU5s9_AVg&bvm=bv.103627116,d.eXY). It allows you to move data from certain web applications to other